# cordova-plugin-file how to upload? cordova version 11

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Previously, before Cordova 11, I remember using `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`, but it no longer works with the latest version of Cordova. There are no sample codes available anywhere on how to upload a file from phone storage to the server with the latest version of Cordova 11 and `cordova-plugin-file`

How can I upload a file from an image gallery to the server using Cordova 11?

ref : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a bug that needs to be resolved by the Apache guys. There's a workaround listed on the GitHub issues for the file transfer plugin (adding a hook to remove the whitelist references in `cordova-file-transfer`): https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/issues/345

Comment: Thanks for replying sir, I have checked and tried all the solutions.. it wont work

Comment: I have applied the hook as provided by one of the users in the forum there. Seems it just allows to build after that but doesn't upload the file

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used the file transfer plugin (just file for opening stuff on / saving to the local device), so I can't really help beyond the build issue. Scoped storage permission issue maybe? It would help to know where the failure is happening (reading the file locally, or writing it to the server)